# Add a loopback audio device in pipewire

Tags: audio

When I was using pulseaudio, it was pretty easy to enable a loopback module, so I could listen to my  mic's input as I was speaking:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

How can a similar effect be achieved with pipewire? `alsaloop` works under pipewire, but seems to be higher latency (if you want a listenable sound) and also has many crackles. Is there a simple replacement for this pulseaudio module?

Answer (score 7):

There has been an update to this where you can use `pw-loopback` instead of `jack_connect`.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're not playing audio through speakers before running this, the feedback I got was jarring to say the least. Very short and good answer.

Comment: Added in [0.3.25](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/releases/0.3.25)

Comment: Just a quick note: If you are using Pulseaudio Volume control app, then you can go to the playbook and recording tabs, and make sure "Show: All streams" is selected (bottom right), otherwise you won't see the loopback interface listed. (this stumped me for a bit) Is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, it turns out, is to use `jack_connect` to connect the input you want to monitor to your ouput. The downside is that this won't track changes in pulseaudio input and output, but it works well.